# A clean way to read a multi-band tiff file from URL?

Tags: python, image, tiff

I have a web service from which I want to load a multi-band image in-memory inside a Python script (ultimately I'll be converting the image into a numpy array). As far as I know packages such as `PIL` and `imageio` don't support this.

What is the preferred way of doing this? I want to avoid saving and reading images to disk.

If I save the file to disk and then load as a multi-band tiff with `tifffile` package things work fine (see code below); but, as I said, I want to avoid reading/writing from/to disk.

```
import requests
import tifffile as tiff


TMP = 'tmp.tiff'


def save_img(url, outfilename):
    resp = requests.get(url)
    with open(outfilename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(resp.content)


def read_img(url):
    save_img(url, TMP)
    return tiff.imread(TMP)
```

Answer (score 2):

The following snippet does the trick. (Note that one should do some additional error checking on response object.)

```
import requests
import tifffile as tiff
import io


def read_image_from_url(url):
    resp = requests.get(url)
    # Check that request succeeded
    return tiff.imread(io.BytesIO(resp.content))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about multi-band images -- if Pillow (née PIL) supports them, fine -- but this is the basic method to load images from URLs in-memory using Requests and Pillow:

```
import requests
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
resp = requests.get('https://i.imgur.com/ZPXIw.jpg')
resp.raise_for_status()
sio = BytesIO(resp.content)  # Create an in-memory stream of the content
img = Image.open(sio)  # And load it
print(img)
```

outputs

```
<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=605x532>
```

Comment: A concrete example of an URL that I worked with: http://services.sentinel-hub.com/v1/wcs/58ab8f33-1d9f-4fdb-8d29-9f8e3d067819?SERVICE=WCS&REQUEST=GetCoverage&COVERAGE=ALLBANDS&FORMAT=image/tiff&MAXCC=100&STYLE=INDEX&FORMAT=image/tiff;depth=8&BBOX=1858948.527895487,5645333.161029979,1868732.4675159894,5655117.100650479&CRS=epsg:3857&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256. The code fails on this particular URL.

Comment: Hmm. Downloading it directly, then converting it to PNG using Imagemagick works (with some warnings). I suppose PIL doesn't support the format, then? (Neither does macOS' Preview, for what it's worth...)

Comment: Yeah, it seems PIL has problems with multi-band tiffs in general.

Comment: Since ImageMagick can read the file, you could look into the ImageMagick (or Wand) Python bindings.

Comment: I've added an example of what I have now: save the image to disk and then load it as a multi-band tiff with `tifffile`. However, I want to avoid read/wiring from/to disk.

Comment: Ahh, alright! Well, reading `tifffile`'s source, looks like you can pass the BytesIO to `imload`: https://github.com/blink1073/tifffile/blob/master/tifffile/tifffile.py#L1217 -- so if you take my example and replace `Image.open` with `tifffile.imload`, things should work.